# Prove that if $x$ is a non-zero rational number, then $\tan(x)$ is not a rational number and use this to prove that $\pi$ is not a rational number.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, pi

> Prove that if $x$ is a non-zero rational number, then $\tan(x)$ is not a rational number and use this to prove that $\pi$ is not a rational number.

I heard that this was proved two hundred years ago. I need this proof because I want to know the proof of why $\pi$ is not rational.

I need the simplest proof!

thanx !

Comment: I don't havea proof but I read that there is one using continued fractions by Lambert http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational#Lamberts_proof

Comment: Pretty sure $\tan 0 = 0$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, ... lol. Any nonzero.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese , ok ! , add other condition that x = 0

Comment: Here's a blog explaining the proof in his own words http://paramanands.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/continued-fraction-expansion-of-tanx/

Comment: There is a translation of Lamberts paper in "Pi - A source book" - Borwein, Jonathan M.; Borwein, Peter B., Pi, a source book

Comment: I've worked out tan(x) as continued fraction here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/288321/58512 - this is the first step of the proof.

Answer (score 4):

Read the excellent book of Ivan Niven, "Irrational Numbers". There is the answer for your interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

The proof from a few hundred years ago was done by Lambert and Miklós Laczkovich provided a simplified version later on. The Wikipedia page for "Proof that $\pi$ is irrational" provides this proof (in addition to some other discussion).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational#Laczkovich.27s_proof

Edit: Proving the more general statement here hinges upon Claim 3 in Laczkovich's proof. 
Defining the functions $f_k(x)$ by
\begin{equation}
f_k(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{k} + \frac{x^4}{2!k(k+1)} - \frac{x^6}{3!k(k+1)(k+2)} + \cdots
\end{equation}
it can be seen (using Taylor series) that
\begin{equation}
f_{1/2}(x/2) = \cos(x)
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
f_{3/2}(x/2) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
\tan x = x\frac{f_{3/2}(x/2)}{f_{1/2}(x/2)}
\end{equation}

Taking any $x \in \mathbb{Q} \backslash \{0\}$ we know that $x/2 \in \mathbb{Q} \backslash \{0\}$ and also that $x^2/4 \in \mathbb{Q} \backslash \{0\}$ as well. Then $x/2$ satisfies the hypotheses required by Claim 3.

Using Claim 3 and taking $k = 1/2$, we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{f_{k+1}(x/2)}{f_k(x/2)} = \frac{f_{3/2}(x/2)}{f_{1/2}(x/2)} \notin \mathbb{Q}
\end{equation}
which then also implies that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{x}{2}\frac{f_{3/2}(x/2)}{f_{1/2}(x/2)} \notin \mathbb{Q}
\end{equation}
Multiplying by 2 then gives $\tan x \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The wikipedia article does have a nice proof; thanks.  I know that Lambert proved the irrationality of $\pi$; did he prove the more general question being asked (and answered) here?

Comment: I've edited my post to add more relevant details.