# how can we convert sin function into continued fraction?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

how can we convert sin function into continued fraction ?

for example

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersContinuedFraction.html

how can we convert sin to simmilar continued fraction ??

and what about sinh and cosh ? arcsin ? arctan ? cos ? arccos ??

in general , how can convert any function to continued fraction ???

my friend asked me this question , so i hope that you help me to be enabled to help him

thanx for all of you

Comment: you may be interested in continued fraction for tan: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287637/how-to-do-a-very-long-division-continued-fraction-for-tan but I don't know how to do sin. I'm sure this will be derived in *Euler - analysis of the infinite*, but I don't have it with me. Of course these  all follow from Gauss' Hypergeometric continued fraction, but it would be nicer to have simple direct derivations.

Comment: There is a continued fraction for sin but I don't know how to derive it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Continued_fraction

Answer (score 10):

We will proceed as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/287987).

Define
$$
P_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{4^{k+n}-\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\binom{2k+2n+1}{2j-1}}{(2k+2n+1)!}(-x^2)^k\tag{1}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{P_{n-1}(x)}{P_n(x)}
&=\frac
{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{4^{k+n-1}-\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\binom{2k+2n-1}{2j-1}}{(2k+2n-1)!}(-x^2)^k}
{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{4^{k+n}-\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\binom{2k+2n+1}{2j-1}}{(2k+2n+1)!}(-x^2)^k}\\[12pt]
&=\color{#C00000}{-x^2+}\frac
{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\color{#C00000}{\binom{2k+2n-1}{2n-1}}}{(2k+2n-1)!}(-x^2)^k}
{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{4^{k+n}-\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\binom{2k+2n+1}{2j-1}}{(2k+2n+1)!}(-x^2)^k}\\[12pt]
&=-x^2+\frac
{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\color{#C00000}{\frac{2n(2n+1)\binom{2k+2n+1}{2n+1}}{(2k+2n+1)!}}(-x^2)^k}
{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{4^{k+n}-\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\binom{2k+2n+1}{2j-1}}{(2k+2n+1)!}(-x^2)^k}\\[12pt]
&=\color{#C00000}{2n(2n+1)}-x^2\color{#C00000}{-}\frac
{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2n(2n+1)\color{#C00000}{\left[4^{k+n}-\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n+1}\binom{2k+2n+1}{2j-1}\right]}}{(2k+2n+1)!}(-x^2)^k}
{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{4^{k+n}-\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\binom{2k+2n+1}{2j-1}}{(2k+2n+1)!}(-x^2)^k}\\[12pt]
&=2n(2n+1)-x^2\color{#C00000}{+2n(2n+1)x^2}\frac
{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\color{#C00000}{\frac{4^{k+n+1}-\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n+1}\binom{2k+2n+3}{2j-1}}{(2k+2n+3)!}}(-x^2)^k}
{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{4^{k+n}-\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\binom{2k+2n+1}{2j-1}}{(2k+2n+1)!}(-x^2)^k}\\[12pt]
&=2n(2n+1)-x^2+2n(2n+1)x^2\color{#C00000}{\left/\frac{P_n(x)}{P_{n+1}(x)}\right.}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
As I [suggested in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8028723#8028723), consider
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(x)
&=\frac{\sin(2x)}{2\cos(x)}\\
&=\frac
{\displaystyle x\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{4^k(-x^2)^k}{(2k+1)!}}
{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-x^2)^k}{(2k)!}}\\
&=x\left/\left(\frac
{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-x^2)^k}{(2k)!}}
{\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{4^k(-x^2)^k}{(2k+1)!}}
\right)\right.\\
&=x\left/\left(1+x^2\left/\frac{P_0(x)}{P_1(x)}\right.\right)\right.\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
$(2)$ and $(3)$ lead us to the continued fraction
$$
\sin(x)=\cfrac{x}{1+\cfrac{x^2}{2\cdot3-x^2+\cfrac{2\cdot3x^2}{\ddots\lower{6pt}{2n(2n+1)-x^2+\cfrac{2n(2n+1)x^2}{P_n(x)/P_{n+1}(x)}}}}}\tag{4}
$$

Comment: Apologies for intruding 4 years later, but isn't $b_2$ supposed to be $2 * 3 - x^2$?

Comment: Yeah, it should be $x^2$ instead of $x^3$

Answer (score 3):

I learned how to do this from this document (look for Theorem I)
https://people.math.osu.edu/sinnott.1/ReadingClassics/continuedfractions.pdf

Interestingly, this looks to be a translation of Euler's original work. I find him easy to understand, he avoids confusing his message in clumsy notation.