# How would you calculate the Tangent without a calculator?

Tags: trigonometry

I was just curious as to how you would calculate it without a calculator. I don't care if it's in radians or degrees, but I just would like it to be specified.

Comment: Learn some values by heart and interpolate.

Comment: @metacompactness:  that's what calculators do...

Comment: @User58220 And he wants to be a human calculator.

Comment: Tables of the tangent function were made by Islamic mathematicians about a millenium ago. If my calculator dies, no problem, it is back to the tables. Any further multiplications needed to find a numerical answer can be done by slide rule.

Comment: There are nice [continued fraction approximations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432771/continued-fraction-for-tannx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Taylor series for sin in radians:$$\sin(x) = x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-...$$ Then calculate tan:$$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{ \sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}}$$

Comment: @DavisDude $\sin^2 (x)$ means $[\sin(x)]^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor series for [$\sin$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+sin+x) and [$\cos$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+cos+x) converge quickly enough that a few digits of accuracy is possible with relatively few computations by hand (generally, computing 2-3 terms will give about two digits of accuracy). Then the division can be carried out.