# Is there another form of $ \tan ( x ) $?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The common form of $\tan(x)$ which depends on Taylor series is $$\tan(x)=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2}{15}x^5+\cdots.$$ Is there an another form of this function depending on other method?

Comment: Yes, that is the Taylor series at $a=0$, you can expand at any other point to get a different Taylor series.

Comment: What do you mean another form? Like a different Taylor Series expansion?

Comment: I mean that the form not depend on Taylor series

Comment: Depends on what you are asking. In the world of Taylor series, not really. But you should look into Fourier Series

Comment: There's a continued fraction, if you like. You have to be more specific about what you want...

Comment: Is there another power series expansion of $\tan$ centered at $0$? No, power series expansions of a function about a given point are unique. To prove this compare their derivatives, which must be equal.

Comment: My teacher told me that there is another form of $tan(x)$ depends on fraction series but he didn't give me it because this is a homework.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/432771/52893

Comment: not this, I need the fraction series

Comment: *My teacher told me that there is another form of $\tan(x)$ depends on **fraction series*** - Could he have meant $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{x-n} ~=~ \frac1x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2x}{x^2-n^2} ~=~ \pi\cdot\cot(\pi x)$ ?

Comment: yes, this is a good answer. Can you give me the source of this form?

Comment: The proof of this formula consists in differentiating the natural logarithm of Euler's infinite product formula for the sine function. See [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) for more information.

Comment: Are you aware that $$\tan(x) = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$$?

Answer (score 0):

As Simon S says, Taylor series centered at a point are unique. The only other different way I could think of writing tangent would be $$\tan(x) =\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} =\frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}}$$ but it is still true that $$\frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}} = x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+ \dots$$